# How to set individual colors in the Activity in android?

Tags: android, colors, android-canvas

I am working on paint application .I am using a colorpickerdialog for picking colors and it is also working fine .Now I am trying to fix only three colors (red,blue,green) in the Activity.

How can I fix three colors in the Activity?

[image: This image consists of all separate colors in the same activity]

This image consists of more colors in the same activity.This is what I am looking for could anyone help me how to do this or give any same program for this?

Comment: you want color picker to return one of the three colors ony??

Comment: no I do not want color picker .I want to show three colors in the activity permanently and user can select any color from that three color and draw the picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have three TextViews with Red, Green and Blue in your activity set onClick listener for all of them and in onClick:

```
    int currentColor=Color.RED;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.red:
        currentColor=Color.RED;
        break;
       case R.id.green:
        currentColor=Color.GREEN;
        break;
       case R.id.blue:
        currentColor=Color.BLUE;
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

}
```